# How to change typesize in the middle of the label in a Matplotlib graph?

Tags: matplotlib

I have plots with two-line labels. Imagine "Inflation" on the top line with "Quarterly, seasonally-adjusted" on the second line. The letters in the second line should be smaller than the letters in the first. It's easy to change the size of the whole label with a `fontdict{}`, but how do I change the size of just the second line in the label?